# What's the dSYM and how to use it? (iOS SDK)

Tags: ios, debugging, compilation, symbols, dsym

Sometimes the compiler produces .dSYM files. I guess this is a debugging related file, but I don't know what it is, and how to use it.

What is a .dSYM? How do I use it?

Comment: A meticulous and excellent explanation can be found in this amazing WWDC 2021 video ⟹ https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10211/ 

Answer (score 207, accepted):

dSYM files store the debug symbols for your app

Services like Crashlytics use it to replace the symbols in the crash logs with the appropriate methods names so it will be readable and will make sense.

The benefit of using the dSYM is that you don't need to ship your App with its symbols making it harder to reverse engineer it and also reduce your binary size

In order to use to symbolicate the crash log you need to drag the crash log into the device's device logs in the organizer of the machine that compiled the app binary (a machine that stores the dSYM)

If you have the dSYM but don't have the machine the compiled the app binary follow the instructions in [this](http://noverse.com/blog/2010/03/how-to-deal-with-an-iphone-crash-report/) link in order to install the dSYM into the machine.

There is a [mac app](https://github.com/inket/MacSymbolicator) that helps you symbolicate a crash log in case you need to do it yourself.

For more information please see [apple technical note TN2151](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

Comment: Will not including dSYMs with an app store binary make Crashlytics not able to log the crashes?

Comment: So it's safe to uncheck the 'Include app symbols...' box?

Comment: if you want to be able to see crashlogs inside apple connect you can include the app symbols when you upload the app to the app store. if you are using crashlytics you don't have to do it but it doesn't hurt to include the app symbols (the dsym file) and send it to apple by checking the "include app symbols..." in the upload to App Store wizard

Comment: I was thinking of saving the user a couple of MBs if it can be done

Comment: From Crashlytics developers - https://twittercommunity.com/t/is-including-dsyms-necessary-to-make-crashlytics-crash-logging-work/68261

Comment: Note that with bitcode enabled, Apple recompiles the codes. That means that different dSYM will be produced.

Comment: @genaks afaik. The entity that produces the reports would need the dSYM. Either it gets it from the app or it should be uploaded to Crashlytics, AppDynamics (or whatever other analytics that you're using) servers...

Answer (score 32):

**Xcode Debugging Symbols(dSYM)**

`dSYM` it is a `Bundle`(e.g `F49088168M.app.dSYM`) which contains a mapping information and with which you can, for example, decode a stack-trace into readable format.

**structure:**

[image]

For example a crash log looks like:

```
//before
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018f3c9380 0x18f394000 + 217984
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018f3c9380 0x18f394000 + 217984
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018f3c8844 0x18f394000 + 215108
3   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018f3a74e0 0x18f394000 + 79072
4   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018f3ab0d8 0x18f394000 + 94424
5   F49088168M                      0x00000001045ac750 0x104590000 + 116560
6   F49088168M                      0x00000001045b7904 0x104590000 + 162052
7   F49088168M                      0x00000001045b897c 0x104590000 + 166268
8   F49088168M                      0x000000010459d914 0x104590000 + 55572
9   F49088168M                      0x00000001045a0e70 0x104590000 + 69232
10  F49088168M                      0x00000001045a0f4c 0x104590000 + 69452
```

`dSYM` in action

```
//after Symbolicating(dSYM is used)
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018f3c9380 closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in _assertionFailure+ 217984 (_:_:file:line:flags:) + 452
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018f3c9380 closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in _assertionFailure+ 217984 (_:_:file:line:flags:) + 452
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018f3c8844 _assertionFailure+ 215108 (_:_:file:line:flags:) + 468
3   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018f3a74e0 _ArrayBuffer._checkInoutAndNativeTypeCheckedBounds+ 79072 (_:wasNativeTypeChecked:) + 208
4   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018f3ab0d8 Array.subscript.getter + 84
5   F49088168M                      0x00000001045ac750 static ELM327ResponseManager.getResponse(responseStr:obd2Protocol:) + 116560 (ELM327ResponseManager.swift:27)
6   F49088168M                      0x00000001045b7904 ELM327Client.dataInput(_:characteristicUuidStr:) + 162052 (ELM327Client.swift:56)
7   F49088168M                      0x00000001045b897c protocol witness for BLEClientInputPort.dataInput(_:characteristicUuidStr:) in conformance ELM327Client + 166268 (<compiler-generated>:0)
8   F49088168M                      0x000000010459d914 BLEConnection.peripheralDataReceived(data:characteristicUuidStr:) + 55572 (BLEConnection.swift:124)
9   F49088168M                      0x00000001045a0e70 BLEConnection.peripheral(_:didUpdateValueFor:error:) + 69232 (BLEConnection.swift:293)
10  F49088168M                      0x00000001045a0f4c @objc BLEConnection.peripheral(_:didUpdateValueFor:error:) + 69452 (<compiler-generated>:0)
```

By default `dSYM` is generated by default for a **release** version.
You can check it:

```
Build Settings -> Generate Debug Symbols(GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS) -> Yes
Build Settings -> Debug Information Format(DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT) -> DWARF with dSYM File
```

The result location you can find in `Products` folder

To generate `dSYM` file manually from `.app` using `dsymutil`

```
dsymutil F49088168M.app/F49088168M -o F49088168M.app.dSYM
```

To symbolicate crash using `symbolicatecrash`

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/symbolicatecrash "<path>/F49088168M-2020-06-04-212904.crash" "<path>/F49088168M.app.dSYM" > symbolicated.crash
```

To open `dSYM` manually using `dwarfdump`

```
dwarfdump --arch arm64 --debug-pubtypes F49088168M.app.dSYM
```

result looks like:

```
0x00000065 "PeripheralLogView"
0x000005cc "BLEConnection"
0x000005da "BLEPeripheral"
0x000005e9 "ELM327Client"
```

*Your .app's dSYM should include all included(framework) dSYMs

[[dSYM location]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63953349/4770877)

[[.bcsymbolmap]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67274795/4770877)

[[Vocabulary]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216151/4770877)