# iphone: Where the .dSYM file is located in crash report

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

According to this page [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html) if you have proper application binary and .dSYM file then it is easy to symbolic them. But where are .dSYM and application binary files located?

Comment: FYI dSYM stands for debug symbol (file)

Answer (score 291, accepted):

Right Click on your `archive -> Show in Finder ->`  Right click on file and click on `Show package contents`.

Here you will find your .dSYM file.

Comment: Yes,Its easy way to access directly without searching path.

Comment: I zipped dSYM and uploaded it to Firebase but it doesn't worked, is there any solution?

Answer (score 120):

You can locate .dSYM and application binary file in archive.

1. Select **Window -> Organizer**

[image: Step 1]

2. This will open up Organizer window containing last created Archive of project
3. Right click on Archive and select '**Show in Finder**'
   [image: Step 3]
4. Select '**Show Package Content**' for archive
   [image: Step 4]
5. Project.xcarchive contains **dSYMs, Info.plist and Products**
   [image: Step 5]

dSYMs folder contains dSYM file of your project.

Application folder in Project contains application binary of your project.

Answer (score 57):

If you have archived your project, you can find the dSYM file as above.

If you have build you project for a real device, you can also find the dSYM file by the following way:

- Go to *Project Navigator*, and find *Products* folder
- Right click the app, and choose *Show in Finder*.

  > Make sure that the app is in black color, not red. Because red color means that you have not build the target for a real device.
- You can find the dSYM file with the same name with your app, in the same folder.

Before all of these actions, make sure you have configured the xcode build settings right, as follows:

- `Generate Debug Symbols` setting is enabled.
- `Debug Infomation Format` are set to `DWARF with dSYM File`.

Hope this will help.

Comment: `Debug Information Format` for Debug can be set to DWARF with dYSM file which lets you get debug symbols without doing the archive dance, thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you for this. Is it possible to regenerate an old dSym that has been overwritten?

Comment: @BradThomas As the dsym file is related with the code base, you cannot get an old dsym file if your code base has been changed.

Comment: awesome answer! I just want to find dsym in debug mode.

Answer (score 46):

I found my `.dsym` file in `/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<appname>/Build/Products/<appname>`

Answer (score 21):

If you removed archive from Xcode's Organizer like me, you can download dsym at the appstore. Select your app, select target version and go to Activity tab. Here you can download desired dsym.[image: Where to download]

Comment: How long I've been waiting for this answer!

Comment: Apparently Apple removed the link, now I don't have it. It was convenient. Have you also lost it?

Comment: @KirillArtemenko, if you told about Activity->All Builds page, it's still exist and allows downloading.

Comment: @Hot'n'Young in Russian iTunes Connect I don't have it anymore.
Example: https://paste.pics/691e2a08c11a6c122c8e5e5c8f165aca

Comment: @KirillArtemenko, my friend from Russia see download button there. Firstly I thought that Apple changed roles permissions. But I checked different permissions for my account (admin, app manager) and saw download dlsym button too. 
Maybe that apple account expired? In this case no such button.

Comment: From Xcode 14 onward, we can’t download dSYM from the App Store Connect anymore. That’s because Bitcode is now deprecated.

Answer (score 12):

In Xcode 5.1.1 you will find it under *Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> DerivedData*. Under *DerivedData* you will see a bunch of random directory names. Find the ones that starts with your project name. Then get the **latest** directory that was created for your project. Then under that directory go to `Build/Products/<Your specific release>/*.app.dSYM`.

You can even click on your end product under "*Products*" in project explorer and do a "*Show in finder*" to get there directly.

Answer (score 7):

The `.dSYM` file should have been generated when you built your application. Look in your build product directory.

Answer (score 6):

If you have the UUID you are looking for, you can search the files with the following command:

```
mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == <UUID>"
```

Answer (score 6):

It's simple. Please follow the steps here:

1. Open your project in **Xcode**, and select the **project file** in the Xcode Navigator.
2. Select your main build target from the **Select a project or target** dropdown.
3. Open the target's **Build Settings** tab.
4. Click **All** near the top of the tab.
5. Search for "**debug information format**".
6. Set **Debug Information Format** to **DWARF with dSYM File**.

Now go to Product > Archive > Your Build > right click on your build and click on *Show in Finder*. Now right click and go to *Show Package Contents* > dSYMs > **Yourappname.app.dSYM**_

Answer (score 4):

1.Select Window -> Organizer

2.Right click on Archive(your app name) and select 'Show in Finder'

3.Select 'Show Package Content' for archive

4.Right click on yourProject.xcarchive contains dSYMs, Info.plist and Products

5.select yourappname.app.dSYM

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't generated an archive and are trying to debug it on the device, dsym can be found at

> /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YOUR_APP/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos

Answer (score 3):

Just one more way to find them all, UUID as a bonus

```
 mdfind -name .dSYM | while read -r line; do dwarfdump -u "$line"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

I just want to share something from my experience. Every time when I release a new version of my framework I save its dSYM in a separate folder. So, later I can find the relevant dSYM easily when I need it. It could be easily done by adding this line of code to the bash script in Build Settings (e.g. in this example I'm saving it to the desktop).

```
cp -r "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework.dSYM" "${HOME}/Desktop/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework.dSYM"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want, you can download them from App Store Connect.

It's under Testflight > Builds > Click your build version code > Build Metadata > Download dSYM

[image: Where to find the Download dSYM button]

Answer (score 1):

[[dSYM]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62219237/4770877)

`.dSYM` is generated near `.app`.`.dSYM` is defined by `Build location`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57512068/4770877). Usually it is a `Derived Data` folder.

For example `F49088168M.app.dSYM` is located

```
/Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/F49088168M-gltfsnpvscodolcmxrvkbaebeppp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/F49088168M.app.dSYM
```

Answer (score 0):

I found `build configuration` should be **`Release`** to generate `.dSYM` file.

Answer (score 0):

First check both of them are in the same configuration - DWARF with dSYM File [image]

If it is okay, then navigate to the following path of your finder or from your terminal

`/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YOUR_APP/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos`

Find App Name and Open Package Content, you will find your .dsym file