# Unable to download dSYM's from Organizer

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, dsym

I am getting an error when trying to download dSYM-files from my app in app store. I am tapping "Download dSYM" in the "Organizer" of Xcode. (See image below)

[image]

The error I am getting is the following:

> Your user account is attached to several iTunes providers. Create
>   separate accounts for each provider before logging in.

[image]

I have recently been added to my customers iTunes connect-account with my apple ID. This is the same apple ID that I am using for private development , and the app that I'm trying to download dSYM for is uploaded via my private account.

How would one solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error. What you need to do is open the archive you want the dSYM from in finder and right click on the archive -> show package contents where you can find the dSYM.

Source:
[iphone: Where the .dSYM file is located in crash report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088771/iphone-where-the-dsym-file-is-located-in-crash-repor)