# Xcode symbolication without an archive

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, archive, crash-dumps

I'm developing an IOS App using Xcode. When I install my App from Xcode and I start it from Xcode, if the App crash then I can see clearly the error in the debugger.

Now, I disconnect my device from Xcode, I start the App and then there's a bug and it crashes. I plug again my device on Xcode and I use the "Device" window to get the crash logs of the App but there's no symbolication and then I cannot analyse the crash :-(

In this situation is there a way to get the symbolication or is it mandatory to first generate an Archive and to install it on the device to get the benefit of the Symbolication?

It will be easier for me, as a Developer to analyse the crash of my App from my Device without having to create and install every time a new archive.

How do you proceed? I'm developing in Swift but I think it's not important...

Thanks for the help,

Seb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, why can't you get the crash information from the debugger?  It'll likely tell you just as much as the crash log is going to tell you...

Second, a symbolication file is built everytime you run a project.  According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12938980/1671729) it's located at:

```
/Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{project}/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
```

That location will change depending on the project and the environment you are building for/debugging.

Comment: When I start my App from Xcode and I have a crash then I use the debugger to find the details of the crash. Next, when my device is not connected to XCode and my App crashes it generates the crash file and then I want to analyze it when I'm back home :-)

Comment: I have found a solution thanks to your answer the linked answer.

In my build settings the parameter "Debug Information Format" was set to "DWARF" for "Debug". I have changed it to "DWARF with dSYM File", then when I'm building my App for debug it generates the DSYM file and when I'm analyzing the crash, Xcode performs automatically the Symbolication.