# How to understand an iOS crash report from crashlytics?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to understand a crash report I've got from crashlytics which looks like this:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  App                            0x104076730 RaceViewController.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) + 4369164080 (<compiler-generated>:4369164080)
1  App                            0x104076800 @objc RaceViewController.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) + 4369164288 (<compiler-generated>:4369164288)
2  UIKitCore                      0x1b6039b24 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 736
3  UIKitCore                      0x1b6007870 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2500
4  UIKitCore                      0x1b60245d8 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 160
5  UIKitCore                      0x1b62f785c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2144
6  QuartzCore                     0x1b888a724 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 284
7  QuartzCore                     0x1b889087c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 468
8  QuartzCore                     0x1b889b3c0 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 140
9  QuartzCore                     0x1b87e3f1c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double) + 296
10 QuartzCore                     0x1b880d8bc CA::Transaction::commit() + 676
11 UIKitCore                      0x1b5e6ca30 _afterCACommitHandler + 140
12 CoreFoundation                 0x1b1d1a06c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1b1d14f60 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 420
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1b1d153dc __CFRunLoopRun + 968
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1b1d14ce8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
16 GraphicsServices               0x1bbe5f38c GSEventRunModal + 160
17 UIKitCore                      0x1b5e43444 UIApplicationMain + 1932
18 App                            0x104066764 main + 13 (Race.swift:13)
19 libdyld.dylib                  0x1b1b9c8f0 start + 4
```

I can see points to two places, `RaceViewController.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` & `Race.swift:13`.

Lets look at those two places in the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let day = self.days[indexPath.section]
    var totalIndex = 0
    var raceIndex = 0
    for selectedRace in racesByDay[day]! {
        if (totalIndex == indexPath.row) {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "raceCell")! as! RaceCell
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.populate(event: self.event!, selectableRace: self.racesByDay[day]![raceIndex])
            return cell
        }
        if selectedRace.opened {
            if (indexPath.row <= totalIndex + selectedRace.race.classes.count) {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "competitorClassCell")! as! CompetitorClassCell
                cell.delegate = self
                cell.populate(competitorClass: selectedRace.race.classes[indexPath.row - totalIndex - 1], selectableRace: selectedRace)
                return cell
            }
            totalIndex += selectedRace.race.classes.count
        } else {
            totalIndex += 1
        }            
        raceIndex += 1
    }
    
    return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "raceCell")!
}
```

and Race.swift:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

class Race {
    var id: String <-- this is line 13
    var name: String
    var viewerUrl: String
    var trackingStartTime: Date
    var trackingEndTime: Date
    var expectedStartDate: String
    var raceStarttime: Date?
    var mapPublicationTime: Date?
    var initialized: Bool

    ...

}
```

How can I understand where the crash happened with this information? I'm not able to reproduce the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Wat you are looking at is referred to as the stack. It's basically the path that was being executed when the crash occurred.

The top of the stack (at index 0) is where the crash really happened and is usually a good place to start.

It's important to figure out the exact line where the crash happened. Sometimes it can be hard to figure out the real line, here it seems to refer to line 4369164080, which doesn't make much sense. Did you upload all the [DSYM Files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports)?

Another hint can usually be found in the `Keys` tab of Firebase/Crashlytics. See if there is a field named `crash_info_entry_0`, this can tell you more about the crash.

In the code sample you posted, I see quite some force unwraps happening, so my first guess would be that one of those turned out to be nil. Perhaps because of a race condition.

Comment: I have downloaded the dSYMs from the app store, four files in total, and uploaded them to crashlytics. But in the dSYM tab in crashlytics I have a list of 21 dSYMs which are optional. Where can I find these files? Maybe one of those is what I need to get the exact line?

Comment: Aah, and the Keys tab is empty.

Comment: If you uploaded all DSYM's from the App Store, that should be enough. Maybe you are also pushing data from older/debug versions? Perhaps those DSYMS's are missing. If you created the build locally, can try and find them as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088771/iphone-where-the-dsym-file-is-located-in-crash-report

Answer (score 0):

I have the same crush. To be on the safe side I would add the following lines:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard self.days.count > indexPath.section else {
        print("Crash is here")
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    let day = self.days[indexPath.section]
    var totalIndex = 0
    var raceIndex = 0
    ...
}
```

Sometimes when you are re-using the tableView and/or changing it's dataSource, tableView may attempt to layout before your dataSource is filled with data. The reason could be some heavy operations or async process. So it's better to check index before subscripting array