# How to get dSYM files for firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, dsym

I am working on an iOS project in which I have integrated the firebase crashlytics which is working but in firebase console it says to upload get dSYM files , How can I get a dSYM file, in latest Xcode 13

[image]

Comment: Make sure Xcode is generating dSYMs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios#check-xcode  Then also configure a run script to automatically upload the dSYMs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios#set-up-dsym-uploading

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28191124/18202989 helped to solve the issue of getting dSYM file from Xcode

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I solved it by  following the steps to get my dSYM file and uploaded into firebase as zip file

> Window -> Organiser -> select archive (right click) -> show in finder
> -> right click archive in finder -> Show Package Content -> dSYM -> (app name).app.dSYM