# What are Parse symbol files?

Tags: parse-platform, crash-reports

What are Parse symbol files? Are those required to effectively log crashes? Parse seems to log crashed even with this not enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The file you are referring to is a dSYM file, this is not Parse specific, but an iOS thing. The file stores debug symbols for your app and it is required to symbolicate crash reports from your app.

See a crash file as an encrypted file, the dSYM file contains all the information a software tool needs to decrypt the data contained in a crash file on iOS.

[Whats the dSYM and how to use it? (iOS SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656391/whats-the-dsym-and-how-to-use-it-ios-sdk)