# Fabric crashlytics showing Missing .dSYM file for latest iOS app version UUID

Tags: ios, swift, crash, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have uploaded several version of iOS app in app store with **Crashlytics** enabled, where some old version got crashed. I am trying to get crash logs from **Crashlytics(fabric)** but it is showing 0 crashes, 'Missing dSYM file', and UUID of latest app version. Here i can upload only .zip file of .dSYM files which has latest UUID, but how can we get older app crash reports(logs).

Comment: you will need .dSYM file to symbolicate crash logs. please view the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656391/whats-the-dsym-and-how-to-use-it-ios-sdk

Answer (score 1):

Uploading symbol files to Fabric

1. In xcode go to Window -> Organiser
2. Find the relevant build that was uploaded to AppStore and click "Download DSYMs"
3. Right-click build and choose "Show in finder"
4. Right-click the selected xcarchive file and choose "Show package contents"
5. Go to DSYMs folder. If you have performed step 2, there should be one file called NP.app.dSYM and some more [Unique UUID].dSYM files (if Bitcode is enabled)
6. Copy all DSYM files, paste in desktop and compress them into one zip
7. Go to https://fabric.io, Click the Settings icon (upper right corner).
8. Go to Apps -> [app name] -> Missing dSYMs and upload the zip

Comment: Arik, i did all this setups earlier and got crash logs of recent app version, but  how can i get crash logs of older app version or both old & latest version?