# How can i get useful information for an exception in release mode?

Tags: flutter, dart

The Exception looks like this:

> {"exception":"Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN
> toInt","stack":"#0 Bs.cXb (zUg)\n#1 _xga.GLb.
> (jVg:958)\n#2 _Efa.pZb (YUg:130)\n#3 _Zca.FYb (zUg:3094)\n#4 _Zca.FYb
> (zUg:3097)\n#5 CA.FYb (zUg:4441)\n#6 RY.Eib (YUg:60)\n#7 Mha.Ohe
> (xVg:464)\n#8 pia.Vie (FV.......

I get the error in the main-function with:

Future main() async {
runZonedGuarded(() async {
...
FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails) {
SendEmail(errorDetails.exception, errorDetails.stack);
......

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`mapping`](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=en) file for Android or [`dSYM`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656391/whats-the-dsym-and-how-to-use-it-ios-sdk) file for IOS.
You can add those file to stores to get readable information or in [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=flutter) if you are use it