# How to generate .dSYM file for .NET MAUI app

Tags: ios, .net, maui, mac-catalyst, dsym

How do I generate symbols file for my .NET MAUI app?

Is it this setting?

`<MtouchNoSymbolStrip>True</MtouchNoSymbolStrip>`

Right clicked project and selected `Properties`. Under iOS > Build, I unchecked `Symbols`. It was originally checked.

[image]

I tried building/publishing with that setting but I still don’t see a `.dSYM` file anywhere in the publish folder.

Comment: Have you tried targeting on a physical iphone device using Release Mode?

Comment: You may check this folder ```YourProject/bin/Release/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/```

Comment: Just tried it in release mode on an iPhone connected to my laptop via USB but I don't see a `.dSYM` file in `/bin/Release/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64` folder. BTW, I'm on Windows. Do I need to be on a Mac? I build my app on GitHub using Actions. I downloaded the artifact.zip file and I don't see a `.dSYM` file in there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on Windows, and the `.dSYM` files are typically generated as part of the iOS build process when building from a Mac, or through a CI/CD pipeline configured for iOS builds, such as GitHub Actions. While you can develop .NET MAUI apps on Windows, for iOS builds, especially to generate `.dSYM` files, you often need to be on a Mac or use a CI/CD system that runs on macOS.

The `<MtouchNoSymbolStrip>` setting is related but might not directly influence the generation of `.dSYM` files. Instead, make sure your iOS project is configured to include debug symbol generation during the build. That is typically controlled by the compiler and linker settings in the iOS project properties.
Make sure the "`Debug Information`" option in your project settings is correctly set up. For Visual Studio on macOS, this can be found under the iOS build settings. Make sure it is set to generate full debug information.

Since you are on Windows, try and build your app on GitHub using Actions, making sure your workflow is configured to run on a macOS runner (like the recent Q1 2024 [macOS 14 (Sonoma) image runner](https://github.blog/changelog/2024-01-30-github-actions-macos-14-sonoma-is-now-available/)), and explicitly include steps to archive and upload the `.dSYM` files as artifacts. That might involve custom scripting within your GitHub Actions workflow to locate and package these files post-build.

```yaml
- name: Archive dSYM files
  run: |
    zip -r dSYMs.zip ${{github.workspace}}/YourAppPath/bin/iPhone/Release/*.app.dSYM
- name: Upload dSYM Artifact
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
  with:
    name: dSYMs
    path: dSYMs.zip
```

See also [SideStore/SideStore workflow](https://github.com/SideStore/SideStore/actions/runs/5169647749/workflow) as an example, with its [`Makefile`](https://github.com/SideStore/SideStore/blob/b78707808de0e48c5edf102be0a7b18513928380/Makefile#L169) setting `DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH` (see [this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/7087?answerId=693294022#693294022) on the default value of `DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH` being `$(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)`).

---

> I'm still struggling with this. I was able to incorporate the steps you mentioned into my GitHub action, but it produced an empty `dSYMs.zip` file. I also found a setting under project properties to include symbols which adds `<IncludeSymbols>True</IncludeSymbols>` to `csproj` file, but this didn't have any effect either. I am not sure if the symbol’s file is being generated at all, or I'm unable to locate it to archive it.

You would need to troubleshoot this: assuming your project's build configuration is set up correctly to generate symbols, and set to [generate full debug information](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/building-your-app-to-include-debugging-information), double-check the location of `.dSYM` files (it should be in the same directory as the compiled application bundle).

```yaml
- name: Find, Echo, and Archive dSYM files
  run: |
    find ${{github.workspace}} -name "*.dSYM" -print -exec echo "Found .dSYM at: {}" \; -exec zip -r dSYMs.zip {} +
```

Try also, in your GitHub Actions workflow, to list the contents of directories where you expect the `.dSYM` files to be generated (to confirm whether the `.dSYM` files are being created and where they are located)

```yaml
- name: List output directory contents
  run: |
    ls -la ${{github.workspace}}/YourAppPath/bin/iPhone/Release/
```

See also "[What's the dSYM and how to use it? (iOS SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3656391/6309)", with this [2020 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62219237/6309).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. However, I'm still struggling with this. I was able to incorporate the steps you mentioned into my GitHub action but it produced an empty `dSYMs.zip` file. I also found a setting under project properties to include symbols which adds `<IncludeSymbols>True</IncludeSymbols>` to `csproj` file but this didn't have any effect either. Not sure if symbols file is being generated at all or I'm unable to locate it in order to archive it.

Comment: @Sam OK. I have edited the answer to suggest some troubleshooting steps.

Answer (score 2):

### On macOS

The `.dSYM` file is generated automatically by Xcode when we [publish a `Release` build of our iOS / MacCatalyst .NET MAUI apps on macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/publish-cli?view=net-maui-8.0) .

For example, here is how to publish a .NET MAUI app for iOS:

```bash
dotnet publish -f net8.0-ios -c Release -p:ArchiveOnBuild=true -p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64 -p:CodesignKey="Apple Distribution: John Smith (AY2GDE9QM7)" -p:CodesignProvision="MyMauiApp"
```

After publishing the iOS/MacCatalyst app using `dotnet publish`, you can find + retrieve the `.dSYM` file using the following steps:

1. Open Xcode
2. In Xcode, in the menu bar, navigate to `Window` -> `Organizer`

   - Alternatively, in Xcode, use the keyboard shortcut `cmd + option + shift + o`
3. In the Xcode Archives window, in the top left corner of the window, use the drop-down to select the app for which you want the `.dsym` file
4. In the Xcode Archives window, on the left-hand menu, select `Archives`
5. In the Xcode Archives window, locate the version of the published app
6. In the right-click menu, select `Show in Finder`
7. In Finder, locate the `.xcarchive` file, `right-click` -> `Show Package Contents`
8. In Finder, you'll now find the `dSYMS` folder where you `.dSYM` file is located

[image]

Comment: You're too kind, @VonC! But your answer is also great and will certainly help @Sam if he doesn't have access to a Mac 